# How to add a static route after a dynamic one in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There are two 2 files with routes.
user.route.js

```
router.get('/user/:id');
```

user-transaction.js

```
router.get('/user/transaction');
```

My architecture looks like this:

```
src/
  user/user.route.js
  user-transaction/user-transaction.route.js
```

I connect all my routes in the project in the following way:

```
   const dirs = await recursive(dir);

    dirs.forEach((res) => {
        if (res.includes('route')) {
            console.log(res);
            const path = `@modules/${res}}`;
            router.use(require(path));
        }
    });
```

The problem is that Express doesn't see the `/user/transaction` route because it connects later than `/user/:id` and thinks `/user/transaction` refers to `/user/:id`.
It seems logical to just move the route higher, but I connect the routes dynamically. That is, it simply takes the files in order and connects the routes in the same order. Is there a solution to this problem or will I have to manually connect all the routes?

Comment: Well, express checks routes in the the order they are registered, and the first one matching is executed. So you have to ensure the correct order of registering ambiguous routes (ie static before dynamic, longer routes before shorter). I don't see how this can be done fully dynamically without an deep analysis of the various routes.

Comment: @bogdanoff what do you think `require(path)` does, if not requiring something that is exported in another file? It's just, that not all `require(..)` are written manually, but just every file meeting certain conditions is `require`d automatically ...

Comment: @derpirscher dang it, I missed that. But I am still not sure why OP is requiring dynamically instead of manually.

Comment: @bogdanoff Because this way, he only has to create the files for a new router and it will automatically be included in the next build without the need of adding the import somewhere ...

Comment: @derpirscher I hope not,  that's straight way to crash app & RCE/CE.

Comment: @bogdanoff Surely, but that's not our decision to make ...